# Is there a way to get the parent of a dataset or group while using Group.visititems?

Tags: python, python-3.x, h5py

I am trying to put an h5py File object into a tree structure so that I can use its ability to print out a representation of the tree to display the contents of a file in the same way the linux "tree" command recursively displays the contents of a directory. The best way to recursively visit all of the items in the file is with the Group.visititems method and passing in the function I will use to add nodes to the tree. Here is what I have so far:

```
import h5py
import argparse
import sys
from anytree import Node, RenderTree

class HDFTree:
    def __init__(self,filename):
        self._file = h5py.File(filename,'r')
        self._root = Node(filename)
        self._node_map = {filename:self._root}
        self._create_tree()

    def _add_node(self,name,item):
        #TODO: Figure out way to get parent of fnode
        parent_node = self._node_map[item.parent] # I don't think item.parent is a thing so this wont work
        self._node_map[name] = Node(name,parent=parent_node)

    def _create_tree(self):
        self._file.visititems(self._add_node)

    def print_tree(self):
        print(RenderTree(self._root))

    def __del__(self):
        self._file.close()
```

Comment: Both `Group` and `Dataset` objects have a `parent` attribute (see the h5py docs).

Comment: Thanks, hpaulj. I discovered this was indeed the case and was able to get what I want with some additional cleanup of the names (see my answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After realizing that the Dataset and Group class both indeed have a parent attribute (also pointed out by hpaulj in a comment on the question) and some cleaning up of the data, I was able to get the output that I want:

```
import h5py
import os
from anytree import Node, RenderTree

class HDFTree:
    def __init__(self,filepath):
        self._file = h5py.File(filepath,'r')
        _,filename = os.path.split(filepath)
        root_name,_ = os.path.splitext(filename)
        self._root = Node(root_name)
        self._node_map = {'':self._root}
        self._create_tree()

    def _add_node(self,name,item):
        _,parent_name = os.path.split(item.parent.name)
        parent_node = self._node_map[parent_name]
        _,child_name = os.path.split(name)
        self._node_map[child_name] = Node(child_name,parent=parent_node)

    def _create_tree(self):
        self._file.visititems(self._add_node)

    def print_tree(self):
        print(RenderTree(self._root))

    def __del__(self):
        self._file.close()
```

The name attribute of Dataset and Group classes apparently gives the full hdf5 path so I cleaned it up with some os.path functions.